# Как называется человек, работающий в отеле на этажах?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Я не думаю, что в России такое распространено, но возможно, например, во Франции есть персонал отеля, которого, например , можно попросить разбудить тебе в определенное время, или там приготовить кофе. Ну так вот, ты его попросишь, и он тебе утром так аккуратненько постучится и скажет: "Бонжур-р-р, мсье! Вы просили разбудить вас."

Существует слово для одного представителя такой профессии?

> Думаю, такие люди должны работать по одному на этаже, но это уж не знаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консье́рж, консье́ржка (**фр.** concierge) — человек, в чьи обязанности входят обеспечение постояльцев в гостинице или жильцов дома всем необходимым и создание для них комфортных условий.
В России профессия консьержа пока не получила широкого признания и распространения. Тем не менее в престижных жилых комплексах и гостиницах они уже широко используются.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Консьерж](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6)

Comment: О как, даже слово французское! Тогда уж точно мерси! А ближайшее, что я смог придумать - это швейцар:)

Comment: У [швейцара](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Швейцар) обязанности немного другие.

Answer (score 0):

Ранее в России готель (Постоялый Двор)существовала "должность" эдакая КОРИДОРНЫЙ. Это совсем не консьерж,а некий лакей что кроме разбудить, чистит сапоги оставленные на ночь в коридоре перед дверью "нумера", комнаты ночлега :) часто и много встречаемо упоминание о КОРИДОРНЫХ  в Русской классике и нетокмо.